# Why would I want to instantiate an object in a base class variable?

Tags: c#, oop

```
BaseClass obj = new SubClass(); // Subclass : BaseClass
```

What does that mean in OOP? When would I want to do that instead of just creating a SubClass object? If someone can give me a real life example I would really apreciate it.

obs: I understand there's some side effects regarding virtual methods and stuff, but what I'm really confused here is about the concept and uses of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple example is to think about a factory class. If one class takes a dependency on some `Factory<T>`, you can inject the "concrete" version, using inheritance. The consuming class doesn't care about *how* the concrete version works, just that it implements some contract.

"What does that mean in OOP?" - In C#, it means that `SubClass` inherits everything about `BaseClass` and has access to everything inside of `BaseClass`, minus private members. By doing this, anywhere a `BaseClass` is required, a `SubClass` may be used in its place. In my example, you might define what a factory should do by exposing an abstract base class. The inheriting class is then free to implement the behavior without any consumers caring about how the work is being done.

(This is only one example--inheritance, when not abused, is a very powerful tool.)

Comment: Why would you ever do that using assignment to a local variable in the same statement, though?

Comment: I'm choosing you because of the real life example and because you've used the word "contract", which really made things clearer for me (:

Comment: One reason may be that `SubClass` has a very noisy interface and you are only concerned with the behavior exposed by `BaseClass`. You may also be getting ready to pass the local variable to some other method/class that requires the base class and want the reminder. I do not do this, personally, but I can think of a few instances when you would want to.

Comment: @hugo_leonardo - Glad I could help. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 3):

The most common reason that I can think of would be in a scope where multiple types of subclass may be assigned to that variable:

```
Vehicle myWheels;

if (iHaveALicense) {
    myWheels = new Car();
} else {
    myWheels = new Bus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have another class which inherits BaseClass:

```
public class NewSubClass : BaseClass
```

When you initialize your object the way you shown, you can do that:

```
BaseClass obj = new SubClass();
obj = new NewSubClass();
```

on the other hand something like that:

```
SubClass obj = new SubClass();
obj = new NewSubClass();
```

wouldn't compile at all.

Answer (score 0):

That would be called polymorphism.

suppose there is a function that takes baseclass as argument.

```
void my_function(Animal ani)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ani.makeSound());
}
```

Now if you make virtual method in the base class and override them in the derived class and then pass any object derived from animal to the function. Then makeSound would make generate sound according to the derived object that you have passed.

That way you don't have to make this function for everytype of animal that produces sound.